# DataAnnotations CustomValidator with Generic Type

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, s#arp-architecture

This is an MVC 3 project using S#arp Architecture.

My domain has several objects that inherit `NamedEntity` which is an abstract class extending `Entity` and defining a `string Name` property.

All of these objects share the fact that they must be unique names across their object type.

Given that the sets of these objects will be relatively small (200 would be an extreme case), I don't mind the round-trip to the database to check if there's a duplicate.

My question is, **what is the best way to easily validate this while keeping to DRY?**

I've gone through a half-dozen iterations, not particularly liking any of them. I've tried creating a `[ValidUniqueName]` attribute on the ViewModel, and the ViewModel can be typed `EditViewModel<T> where T: NamedEntity`. The problem comes that the attribute doesn't know the correct repository / tasks object to talk to because of the Generic.

To work around that, I tried creating a `INamedEntityTasks<T>` reference in the ViewModel, and accessing it from the `ValidationContext` for the `ValidUniqueName` attribute. That doesn't work as expected, because the Attribute isn't generic (it can't be) and therefore it doesn't know how to properly cast the `ValidationContext.ObjectInstance` back into something usable.

At this point, the only thing I can think of is to create separate `[ValidUniqueFoo]` `[ValidUniqueBar]` etc. attributes, which seems bad. Alternatively, I can put the validation in each controller, but that's equally bad it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it seems like it's going to involve dirty hacks or some seriously complicated code (see other answer). It's not awful to have to write

```
public class ValidUniqueCityAttribute : ValidationAttribute {

public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is CityCreateOrEditViewModel)) return base.IsValid(value);

        INamedEntityTasks<City> tasks = new NamedEntityTasks<City>();

        CityCreateOrEditViewModel vm = value as CityCreateOrEditViewModel;
        return !tasks.CheckForDuplicateName(vm.Entity.Id, vm.Entity.Name);
    }
}
```

For each NamedEntity then, we Copy & paste, search & replace... yes, it's redundant, but it does have the advantage that it allows for greater flexibility, if for instance we wanted to validate City names in some other way than Categories (like looking up a master list of all the cities in a given state, for example, although that is completely contrived and horrible practice :)).

Comment: That looks good, but I am sure you can make that more generic. I need to think about that one.

Comment: Let me know what you come up with! I'm definitely interested in finding a more generic solution. If `tasks` isn't typed correctly (for example, if it's typed as the base `NamedEntity`, you can get false positives (you have a Category named Foo but it won't let you create a City named Foo). I tried modifying `CheckForDuplicateName` to take the `NamedEntity` object and compare type, but `typeof(City)` doesn't match `typeof(NamedEntity)` so that doesn't work either.

Comment: I am getting there! Using reflection, but I am getting false negatives. I will post more once I have more.

Comment: So after a lot of trail and error, I have come to the conclusion that it is in fact not possible to make this more generic. Attributes don't seem to like being past arguments that are not compile time constants, which means no delegates. I think the solution you have above is probably as good as it will get, which is a shame as I would love to see an attribute work for more than one situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! Now we just have to go pressure the C# team to implement generic attributes and this whole problem goes away!

Comment: Agreed! It does seem daft to me that you can't use generics in attributes, but I'm sure there is a very good reason!

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply add an overloaded constructor to the `[ValidUniqueName]`? Or have I completely missed the point?

**EDIT**

Could you pass two type parameters to your `ViewModel` something like

```
ViewModel<T, TRepository>
```

Comment: What would the constructor take as its argument(s)? So I have
`[ValidUniqueName(...)]
public class EditViewModel<Foo>` ... Not quite sure what I can pass in to help. I suppose I could hack it with `ValidUniqueName(typeof(T))` but that's definitely going to be a hack.

Comment: Yes I see your point. I think passing the `typeof(T)` param would be the cleanest solution, when using an overloaded constructor, but as you say, it would be a dirty hack.

Comment: I still don't know if that's going to work. In order to call a function like `CheckForDuplicateName`, I need a typed instance of `INamedEntityTasks<>`. Even using Reflection to create something (like in http://omegacoder.com/?p=38) I still need to know what that type is going to be before I can use it (line 7 in the linked example).

Comment: Even trying to do something like `ValidFooAttribute` and `ValidBarAttribute` (class explosion) both inheriting from `ValidUniqueNameAttribute` doesn't seem like it's going to work. I can do implementations of both classes with no relationship to each other, each creates its own `Tasks` object and calls CheckForDuplicateName ... it's only a few lines of repeated code, but it is repeated. It might be the least ugly solution.

Comment: I share your passion for keeping things DRY but I'm afraid without knowing your code I can't be of much help I'm sorry. I have edited my answer with a possible suggestion but I'm not sure how you would go about implementing this.

Comment: Hm. Via dependency injection you can definitely get the Repository (or Tasks) object there. So now we 1) process `IsValid()` with `ValidationContext`, 2) cast that into the most generic ViewModel we can (`NamedEntityViewModel<NamedEntity>`) and 3) access its .Tasks or .Repository property. That might work, although step 2 may cause issues... I forget if I can cast from `ViewModel<Foo>` to `ViewModel<NamedEntity>`